# How to show a WCFinformation in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, xaml

I have a Silverlight application that displays a map, and my intention is, when I mouse over a specific location in the map, the information about this location gets displayed somehow in the app. What I've done so far is to link the silverlight app to a webservice that retrieves this information for me, but now I'm stuck, and don't know how to proceed. I was following [this tutorial.](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid-cs/), but when the tutorial wants to retrieve a list, I want to retrieve a single object. I was trying to use the datagrid, but I think it was not designed to perform what I want. I need some enlightment to tell me how to proceed.

Well ... I'll edit the code to show what problem I'm having. My code behind have this two methods:

```
private void MouseOverHarbor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ellipse thisPath = (Ellipse)sender;

            thisPath.Stroke = mySolidColorBrush;
            DataRetrieverReference.Service1Client webService = new DataRetrieverReference.Service1Client();
            webService.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<DataRetrieverReference.GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetDataCompleted);

            webService.GetDataAsync((int)thisPath.DataContext);      

        }

        void webService_GetDataCompleted(object sender, DataRetrieverReference.GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            NameField.Text = "Works";//No, it doesnt!            
        }
```

What I can see is that the event handler is never reached, but I don't know why. I just used the same code the tutorials taught, but I didn't achieve my goal yet. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The body of your question refers to getting data from a web service and displaying it in a grid, but the title of your question refers to showing "a database information." If you only need to know how to communicate with the web service, the database aspect of this question is irrelevant. Could you give more information about what kind of data you are trying to retrieve and how you wish to present that data to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `List<    >` part from `List<Customer>` in your calls and keep only the `Customer` part.

Change your queries from

```
var matchingCustomers = from cust in db.Customers
                        where cust.LastName.StartsWith(lastName)
                        select cust;
return matchingCustomers.ToList();
```

to

```
var matchingCustomers = from cust in db.Customers
                        where cust.LastName.StartsWith(lastName)
                        select cust;
return matchingCustomers.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The problem is that the Silverlight data grid wont allow me to use a non-enumerable value in the ItemsSource field.

Comment: @Bruno: Why would you use a grid to display a single value? Another control might be more suitable. If you want to convert a single value to a List you can do: List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>{singleCustomer};